# Can a record type be a part of many business processes?

Tags: record

I *kind of* understand the difference between a record type and a business process.  But, I am not comfortable with my understanding.

Can a record type be a part of (or associated with) many business processes?

Comment: Munira, what would you consider a "business process" ? A technical or business meaning ? Clarifying this, will make it easier to understand your confusing and provide you with a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Each record type may have one business process. A business process many participate in many record types.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly design your record types based on your company's business processes. Whether you associate one/many record types to one/many business processes is up to your unique requirements.

Personally, I would begin by outlining the basic functionalities that record types provide. Generally, they give the ability to:

- associate different page layouts, which can be associated to different profiles.
- associate default record types to different profiles.
- offer different picklist values.

If it looks like my requirements could benefit from the above functionalities, then I would definitely consider record types.

Hope that helps.